# How to get a DataTable object from a database using its tablename in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I'm trying to get a DataTable object out of a database using a table name that I have already. (I mean I want to choose between multiple tables. For this I only have a string which represents a table name. So I'm looking for a way to get my hands on the actual object.)

How can I do that?

I have already tried:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable(TableName);
```

But I believe this is wrong. (How is the application supposed to know where that table name comes from or where to search for it?)

I tried using `con.GetSchema("Tables")`, but that gives out only table names which are strings, and not DataTable objects. I also tried this but it seems DataTables are not enumerable:

```
public static DataTable GetTable(string TableName, string conncetionstring)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conncetionstring);
    foreach (DataTable table in con.GetSchema("Tables"))
    {
        if (table.TableName == TableName)
        {
            return table;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: why exactly `DataTable`? why not use EF, SubSonic, NHibernate, ...?!

Comment: can you explain more Andreas Niedermair?

Comment: Hossein, [you know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141790/can-you-please-add-a-bookmark-feature-to-site#comment401590_141790) there's no excuse to not uppercase sentences, nor for the odd spacing before punctuation. Please fix that?

Comment: Nice. I fixed a bit more, but your effort was good enough for an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.  the schema needs to come somewhere 
Here is typical code I use to connect and get a table.

```
string Sql="SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1=0";
string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=MYDATA.MDB;"

OleDbConnection new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql, conn);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Here is a article from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suprotim/oledbschema09032005054630am/oledbschema.aspx dealing with retrieving schema for tables.

Comment: by the way what does that "WHERE 1=0" mean ? would it not give an empty datatable ? with no rows ? cause 1 never equals to 0 and thus no row will be selected !!
cant we just say "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE" ?

Comment: WHERE 1=0 is a way of getting an empty structure. It works from MS Access and SQL server.  Not sure about MySQL.

Comment: so i was right then :) 
by the way shouldnt we open the connection prior to using adapter? or close it afterwards?